# Plotting 2 pie charts side by side in MatPlotLib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to create 2 pie charts in Matplotlib. Although currently my codes allows me to print out 2 pie charts, but they are printed out in a vertical direction. Is there any way that i can make the pie charts be printed side by side horizontally?

This is my current code that only allows me to print 2 pie charts vertically:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#read the csv file
filename = '../LAB03-DATA VISUALIZATION USING MATPLOTLIB/singapore-residents-by-ethnic-group-and-sex-end-june-annual.csv'
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype=['i8','U50','i8'], delimiter=',', names=True)

#extract datas that are of 1960
data_1960 = data[data['year'] == 1960]

#extract datas that are of 2016
data_2016 = data[data['year'] == 2016]

#extract datas that have this keyword 'TOTAL MALE RESIDENTS' and 'TOTAL FEMALE RESIDENTS'(1960)
male_and_female_1960 = data_1960[np.isin(data_1960['level_1'], ['Total Male Residents' , 'Total Female Residents'])]

#extract datas that have this keyword 'TOTAL MALE RESIDENTS' and 'TOTAL FEMALE RESIDENTS'(2016)
male_and_female_2016 = data_2016[np.isin(data_2016['level_1'], ['Total Male Residents' , 'Total Female Residents'])]

# PLOTTING OF THE 1960 PIE CHART-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
labels = male_and_female_1960['level_1']
values = male_and_female_1960['value']

#settings and configs for the pie charts
colors = ['#FF8F33','#33FFDC']
explode = (0.1, 0)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.pie(values,labels = labels,colors = colors,autopct = '%1.1f%%')
plt.title('Gender Composition in 1960')

# PLOTTING OF THE 2016 PIE CHART-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
labels = male_and_female_2016['level_1']
values = male_and_female_2016['value']

#settings and configs for the pie charts
colors = ['#FF8F33','#33FFDC']
explode = (0.1, 0)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.pie(values,labels = labels,colors = colors,autopct = '%1.1f%%')
plt.title('Gender Composition in 2016')

plt.show()
```

My current output.

[image: Pie Chart Image Output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can -

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(10,10)) #ax1,ax2 refer to your two pies

# 1,2 denotes 1 row, 2 columns - if you want to stack vertically, it would be 2,1

labels = male_and_female_1960['level_1']
values = male_and_female_1960['value']
ax1.pie(values,labels = labels,colors = colors,autopct = '%1.1f%%') #plot first pie
ax1.set_title('Gender Composition in 1960')


labels = male_and_female_2016['level_1']
values = male_and_female_2016['value']
ax2.pie(values,labels = labels,colors = colors,autopct = '%1.1f%%') #plot second pie
ax2.set_title('Gender Composition in 2016')
```

Comment: Sure no problem :)